# Dynamically load new body

Tags: apache-camel

On my route I need to load a new body from a file, based on a reference to the filename in the original body.

In more detail:

I have two files, one xml file (1) which contains metadata about the second file, e.g. the full path of the datafile (2).

1. file EP reads xml file from filesystem
2. find full path to the **datafile**
3. load the **datafile** as new message body (or aggregate them)

Is there a component for that? Or do I need to code that myself?

Thx

Comment: elaborate with some route example

Comment: You can just use content-enricher and put the file path as a header and then feth the datafile to the new message body. That is out of box Camel functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the content-enrincher. Something like this to get you started:

```
from("direct:start").setHeader("filename", constant("datafilepath").enrich().simple("file://${headers.datafilepath}") .log("${body}");
```

Comment: Great! Tranks a lot